# Add category of each element in a form

Tags: symfony

Well, currently I have something like this:

[image: simple form]

And I would like to add categories appears before filters, like this:

[image]

My form code:

```
        $formFilter = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('_',     EntityType::class,array(
                        'class' => 'loicFilterBundle:Filter',
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'expanded' => true,
                        'choice_label' => function($value) {
                        return ($value->getName());
                        },
                        ))
                ->add('Appliquer filtres', SubmitType::class)


                        ->getForm();
```

How to add categories before ?

Thanks for help :) .

**EDIT**:

I finally succeeded by doing it in the twig view(but also need to let group by in the controller):

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {% for group in form.filterfilter.vars.choices %}
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <h3>{{ group.label }}</h3>
            {% for value in group.choices %}
                {{ form_widget(form.filterfilter[value.value]) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `group_by` option ([see doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#group-by)) ?

Something like :

```
$formFilter = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('_', EntityType::class,array(
        'class' => 'loicFilterBundle:Filter',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'choice_label' => function($value) {
            return $value->getName();
        },
        'group_by' => function($value) {
            return $value->getCategory()->getName();
        },
    ))
    ->add('Appliquer filtres', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();
```